# MYSQL REPLACE in QUERY and CDATA output usage still causes broken XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a PHP script that queries a MySQL database and displays that information in XML format output.

I have a troublesome column that I have no control over (I can only SELECT).  This column is filled with character returns etc.

In the MySQL query, I have tried to use REPLACE on this column like this:

```
REPLACE(PropertyInformation, '\r\n', '') AS PropertyInformation
```

In the PHP script I also wrap the exported XML in CDATA as I was told this could help, like this:

```
<Description><![CDATA[' . $PropertyInformation . ']]></Description>
```

I also form the XML like this in the script:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: By changing back your question you're only making it less readable to people

Comment: No problem...I thought it made sense the first time out personally.  I adjusted it again.  Makes more sense, hopefully I can get some help on it.

Comment: it's broken since it is not valid UTF-8. try converting the data to UTF-8.

Comment: @eis when forming the XML output I specify this.  Is that what you mean?  header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco yes, that specifies what charset you claim the data to be. But you have to also obey what you specify, your data has to be UTF-8 if you claim it so.

Comment: The _data_ you are putting into your document is not valid UTF-8 – and of course putting a sticker on it saying “this is UTF-8 encoded” like you are doing with your XML prolog does not change that fact in any way. So the solution is simple – output data in UTF-8 when you say that’s what you are doing.

Comment: @CBroe - That makes sense, is there a way to specify UTF-8 results within the SELECT statement?   How is this done?

Comment: Are you specifying the correct charset to use for your database _connection_ already …? (If not, MySQL will transcode the data to the charset used for the connection, not matter if the data might be stored correctly as UTF-8 already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is broken since your data is not UTF-8 even though you claim it to be (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)

You need to convert your data to this format.

There are three ways to do that, either

1. convert your data in the database to be UTF-8, or
2. convert doing a select statement, or
3. convert in PHP the data to be UTF-8, leaving the data in the database as-is.

First option you would do by taking a dump of the database, issuing iconv conversion command to it and importing it back.

Second you would do with `SELECT CONVERT(latin1column USING utf8) ...`

Third you would again do with iconv, assuming your data would be ISO-8859-1: `$converted = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $text);`

Comment: I tried converting the table like this: ALTER TABLE table1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;  and am getting the same results...do I need to convert the entire database?  I confirmed the column is   `PropertyInformation` text collate utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT 'Property Information', and the database itself is 65001 (UTF-8)  @eis

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco first of all, if you plan to convert the database content, please have the backups first before you do any conversions and then plan first what you do before you do. :) you can mess your data if your not careful.

Comment: Second, investigate what character set you have there now. Is the data messed up in a way that it's not any kind of valid characters or some proper charset?

Comment: ...Yes, the currently database says its 65001 (UTF-8) and the properties of the table is PropertyInformation text collate utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Boom!  I had 2 columns causing a problem ...  fixed with the SELECT CONVERT(latin1column USING utf8) in the query.  Awesome, thanks!